# How to correct an odd right alignment in ListView items

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the ListView setup below, but the items in the view are always appearing slightly to the right of centre, even if I try to horizontally align left. It's particularly apparent when using selection that the labels aren't quite in the right place. It's hard to tell but you can just about see it in this screen capture:
[image: ListViewItems]

On the test001 you can perhaps tell it is closer to the right than left (selection shows it easier but doesn't get picked up with the sniptool.

The xaml is:

```
<ListView x:Name="listImages" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
        <ListView.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="elementContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="_Close" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ImagesContextProxy}, Path=DataContext.Close}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource elementContextMenu}"/>
            </Style>                
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Selector.BorderBrush" Value="Cornsilk"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" Padding="1" MaxWidth="200" Background="#FF8787EE"
                           Content="{Binding ImageModel.ImageName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding ImageModel.ImageName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: I think you need to set Margin="1 2 1 2" instead of Margin="2" , because in the center you have 4 pixel margin now 2px from left control + 2px from right control

Comment: I just test your code with the same data ("test001" and "bmw") and they are exactly centered here. I think something else is causing the problem.